# Pandas | Group by with all the values of the group as comma separated

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

As per application requirement, I need to show all the data which is part of group by in comma separated format so the admin can take decision, I am new to Python and not sure how to do it.

**Sample reproducible data**

```
import pandas as pd

compnaies = ['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Google']
products = ['OS', 'Search', 'E-comm', 'X-box', 'Social Media', 'Android']

df = pd.DataFrame({'company' : compnaies, 'product':products })
-----------------------------------------------------------------   
    company     product
0   Microsoft   OS
1   Google      Search
2   Amazon      E-comm
3   Microsoft   X-box
4   Facebook    Social Media
5   Google      Android
```

Now I getting count of company group by this code

```
df.groupby(['company']).count()
```

I need data in below mentioned format but not sure how to get it

**Desired output**

```
company    count product
Amazon      1    E-comm
Facebook    1    Social Media
Google      2    Search, Android
Microsoft   2    OS, X-box
```

Comment: were you able to convert company as a column when converting it into an excel file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use:

```
In [35]: df.groupby('company').product.agg([('count', 'count'), ('product', ', '.join)])
Out[35]: 
           count          product
company                          
Amazon         1           E-comm
Facebook       1     Social Media
Google         2  Search, Android
Microsoft      2        OS, X-box
```

Comment: @Iiliscent How to give column to these columns instead of count and product?

Comment: @panda What do you mean by "give column"? Those *are* columns.

Comment: i think he wants the company as a column too because when converted into an excel file there no column for "company"

Comment: df=df.reset_index()

Comment: How to access the "product" column if my column is named with a space separated string? Like if it was "product name" in this case, the dot notation would not work