# transpose list of country codes to material code pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to create a list of country codes based on a particular material number

My data has multiple countries for each material number.
Data is as follows.

```
Material number Country code
323043          CZ
323043          IE
323043          GB
323043          FR
223392          IE
223392          NL
223392          DE
113224          RU
```

I would like the list be made like this, even a new column with a list will do

```
Material number Country code
323043          CZ, IE, GB, FR
223392          IE, NL
113224          RU
```

What's the best way to do this in pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby('Material number')['Country code'].apply(', '.join)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas | Group by with all the values of the group as comma separated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422809/pandas-group-by-with-all-the-values-of-the-group-as-comma-separated)

Comment: I've tried that solution but I get an error, TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, float found

Comment: cast as `str` first..? `df.astype(str).groupby('Material number')['Country code'].apply(', '.join)`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.